# How to randomize between two set colors?

Tags: colors, processing

I want to know how to be able to have my program generate random color between two set colors and all inbetween the two.  For example just the way that I would say:

```java
fill(random(255),0,0));
```

in order to get a range reds.

I want to be able to choose two colors, let's say orange and blue, and have it generate colors from these two sets of colors. So for it to randomly generate a color from that shade of blue, any shade in between that and into a specific shade of orange.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You probably want to use [lerpColor](https://processing.org/reference/lerpColor_.html) and randomize the `amt` parameter in this function between 0.0 and 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have 3 variables that hold the "base" color:

```java
float baseR = 50;
float baseG = 100;
float baseB = 200;
```

You could then add a random number to those values to get a new shade "around" that color:

```java
float shadeDistance = 10;

float r = baseR + random(-shadeDistance, shadeDistance);
float g = baseG + random(-shadeDistance, shadeDistance);
float b = baseB + random(-shadeDistance, shadeDistance);

fill(r, g, b);
```

Or if you have two colors that you want to blend, you can use the [`lerpColor()`](https://processing.org/reference/lerpColor_.html) function:

```java
stroke(255);
background(51);
color from = color(204, 102, 0);
color to = color(0, 102, 153);
color interA = lerpColor(from, to, .33);
color interB = lerpColor(from, to, .66);
fill(from);
rect(10, 20, 20, 60);
fill(interA);
rect(30, 20, 20, 60);
fill(interB);
rect(50, 20, 20, 60);
fill(to);
rect(70, 20, 20, 60);
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [processing.org](https://processing.org/reference/images/lerpColor_.png))</sub>